# My Logo doesn't display at the correct position in actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-actionbar

I wrote this code into my Activity and my logo displays, but it has a space before the logo

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.emenu_logo);
    setTitle("");
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I don't know how to fix that, please help me!

Comment: try `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);`

Comment: I tried, but it disappear @@!

Comment: you can make custom actionbar and put your required stuff there..

Comment: yes, I have made custom actionbar to change color of it. What do you mean ???? @@!

Comment: I mean to make a layout file and inflate it to your actionbar so you can easily put what ever you want

Comment: Oh wow, but how can i do that ??

Comment: You mean put a layout into resource file ????

Comment: use `ToolBar` instead of `ActionBar`.

Comment: simply remove this or false this getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.emenu_logo);

Answer (score 1):

Make a layout and inflate in your custom action bar...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);   // inflate layout file

    /// TextView,ImageView,Button  etc element 

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
   }
}
```

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer , really... cause all you did is gave him a link

Comment: Are there anything else ? NullPointerException @@!

Comment: i have updated answer, and by the way how you are initializing view here?