# Android custom ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to reproduce a product detail layout like this one from trivago app [image]

but I never get the actionbar like the above, here's my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/galleryPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gallery_pager_overlay"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1/8"
                android:id="@+id/tvPicNum"
                android:background="@drawable/background_viewpager_bubble"
                android:textColorLink="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/galleryPager"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tbTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="test this title"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="12dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/l5_stars"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/content_product_details" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And my result looks like this :
[image]

And this is my Activity code :

```
public class ProductDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hotel_details);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    product = (Product)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("selectedProduct");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(product.getTitle());
    new getProductGallery().execute();
}
```

So, please help with the correct way to do that

Thanks

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: 1) SO is not for "how to.." types of questions, it's about issues or problems. 2) you should look at the Toolbar documentation. you'd be surprised.

Comment: try to make custom action bar..check [my this answre](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33800352/2553431)

Comment: The issue, is that I can't increase the title size to get it like the first one, is that the right way with this kind of actionbar or not ?

Comment: The titles look similar to me, what's wrong with it specifically? The font?