# How to add Textview below Actionbar title

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image: reference image with text below title]

how can we add a Textview below default actionbar title?

I have googled it and tried with custom Actionbar View, but it will change other Actionbar functionality. Any reference?

Comment: check my [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33800352/2553431) answer

Comment: i have mentioned that i had tried with costume Actionbar view,so its not helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setSubtitle` .

> Set the action bar's subtitle. This will only be displayed if
>   DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE is set. Set to null to disable the subtitle
>   entirely.

```
ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); //getSupportActionBar()
 ab.setTitle("App Title");
 ab.setSubtitle("App sub-title");
```

You can check **[Setting Action Bar title and subtitle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297178/setting-action-bar-title-and-subtitle)**

Answer (score 2):

add this code to your code

```
        ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.setTitle("My Title");
        ab.setSubtitle("sub-title");
```