# How to display and set click event on Back Arrow on Toolbar?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-menu

[image: Back button on toolbar]

How can I set back arrow in Android toolbar and also apply click listener?

Comment: make custom action bar...check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33800352/2553431)

Comment: Related post - [Display Back Arrow on Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26651602/465053)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

First make one `toolbar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

then include it in `activity_main.xml` like this way:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</LinearLayout>
```

then in your `MainActivity.java` file, put this code:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MyTitle");
```

To add listener on back press, use following method:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // todo: goto back activity from here

            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you HAVE to create a toolbar?  Why not an app bar

Answer (score 50):

```
Toolbar mToolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);    
mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // perform whatever you want on back arrow click 
    }
});
```

// with lamda expression

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(view -> onBackPressed());
```

Comment: In my case, you must add the listener after setSupportActionBar or it won't work.

Comment: What @JiaweiYang is important, it'd be good if you add to your answer...(+1)

Comment: the lamda version doesn't work i get error `Lamda expression are not supported at language leve 7`

Answer (score 21):

If you are using the default back button for android by using

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then override the onOptionsItemSelected like

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //do whatever
            return true;
        default:
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Complete example here** http://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-add-back-arrow-in-android-activity/

Use **getSupportActionBar()** Activity on which you want to show Back Icon

In **OtherActivity.class**

```
public class OtherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.other_activity);


    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}
```

}

This will add a event listen

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know when home is clicked is an AppCompatActivity then you should try it like this:
Use this code :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Listen for click events on android.R.id.home like usual:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

and in `onOptionsItemSelected` add this

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Check this

[Display Back Arrow on Toolbar Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26651602/display-back-arrow-on-toolbar-android)

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer (score 3):

Very simple code. Add inside `onCreateView()` method of activity

To display icon

```
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and to add click listener

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Put your click logic here
            }
        });
```